# virt-manager - spice-guest-tools not working on Windows 10 guest

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, qemu, linux-kvm, spice

Host: Debian Bullseye
Guest: Windows 10 20H2
Hypervisor Details:

> Hypervisor: KVM 
> Architecture: x86_64
> Emulator: /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64
> Chipset: Q35
> Firmware: BIOS

Windows in the VM is running well, but I notice that the Spice Agent process is constantly eating up a whole CPU core on the system. Despite all that "work", neither shared clipboard, nor auto-resizing work. Virt-manager says the Spice Agent cannot be detected on the guest.

Deciding to investigate the Services, I look for any services with SPICE, KVM and/or QEMU in their name. I find that the `Spice VDAgent` service is running, but the `QEMU Guest Agent` is not running, despite being set to Automatic. When I try to start it, it fails, saying

> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

When I try to run the executable for that service manually in cmd (`C:\Program Files\qemu-ga\qemu-ga.exe`), it blurts out the following

> 1646973410.401573: critical: error opening path 
> 1646973410.401573: critical: error opening channel 
> 1646973410.401573: critical: failed to create guest agent channel 
> 1646973410.401573: critical: failed to initialize guest agent channel

After some googling I discover this output is due to the QEMU Guest Agent being unable to find a channel. I don't really know what that is, but, under `Virtual Hardware Details`, I did notice that the Channel spice device has been set to `com.redhat.spice.0`. So I tried to replace it with a Channel `org.qemu.guest_agent.0`. But after doing so, the VM fails to start, saying that `org.qemu.guest_agent.0` is an `Unsupported spicevmc target name`. Setting it back to the RedHat setting lets the VM start again, but the problem with spice-guest-tools persists.

I tried reinstalling spice-guest-tools, but that also does not fix the issue. What is going on here? Is it possible to get spice-guest-tools working with this setup, or should I just switch to VirtualBox or VMWare?

Comment: How did you install the guest additions? How does your device manager look like?

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into the same issue and after a lot of testing, I've managed to find the issue.

## Make sure your vm has the following components:

- **Video**: QXL
- **Graphic**: Spice server
- **Channel**: spacevmc
- **controller**: virtio-serial
- **network**: virtio
- **drivers**: Spice guest-tools, **virtio driver** (very important)

I hope it helped!

Comment: It you have time, it would be quite useful to have the command output of your virt-manager (not sure if `ps aux | grep qemu` would work) for people who otherwise use the command-line flags. Thanks whether or not you do this.